# MultiDatabase based architecture for Web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

If we have an ASP MVC4 web application and we have to provide it to multiple companies with their logins, what should be the best way with respect to database architecture.
Should we make separate dbs for each company and on url bases we will connect with respective database?
Or should we make one db and use a key for each company?

Because each company will be using the same web application but with its own records.

I am still confused about it because if we make separate dbs for like 100 companies and we need to change a column or cell of db or we want to do updates in our software we will have to change it in 100 dbs. So is there some way Microsoft provides for SQL Server 2008R2.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As shown my practice, often different companies wants different functionality or additional features for some parts of web-application. So better will be to separate not only db but web app also. 
Also question is it intranet or internet solution? If intranet - no questions. If internet -use third level domain name and separate db for each company. It will give you more flexibility.

Comment: I'd avoid making databases and apps different for each customer because it does not scale. Once you have 1000 or so databases it gets out of hand if you have to treat each one separately.

Comment: @MartinBrown if each client wants specific functionality, design or additional modules? 1000 cases in server code?

Comment: can only add, that if you go this way, you probaply want to use Migration Project or `SQL Server Database Project` in VS in your solution that will contain all changes in Base logic

Comment: My point is that doing different things for each customer is not a business model that scales. Because it is not just the code that has to adapt to each customers requirements it is also the developers and admin staff. You need a model where customers can do what they want with configuration.

Comment: @aleha If each client wants specific functionality,design etc. You no longer have one system. You now have a different system for each client.

Answer (score 1):

This is not as simple to answer as it sounds as it depends upon exactly what you are doing.

Microsoft have quite a good paper on this which I strongly recommend you read before you start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

At our firm we use one database for each client and a main database to keep track of which databases we have and what server they are on. We also have a couple of other databases for aggrigated reporting and keeping track of background processes. We only have one web site accessing those databases which works well for us.